# How do you take the value of a time formatted cell and put it into another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a sort of timesheet for my new job.  I have got to a point where it has worked out the hours for me, but it won’t add up each day’s hours into a total correctly.

For example:
Cells **C19:G19** have all time formatted cells.
`C19` has **07:20:00** for my hours worked that day.
When using the `SUM(C19:G19)` function for all the cells in that range, I’m getting **11:40** back. When in reality this value should be nearly **37:00**.

Is there anyway to either correct this or extract the numbers so I can get the right number?

Comment: Welcome! It seems that you have a typo in your question - five days after 07:20 should have been displayed as **12:40** (not **11:40**). Actually the result of the `SUM()`  function for this case will be ***"one day (24 hours) and also 12:40"***, but the current cell format only shows the last part of this result. Try pressing **Ctrl+1** for this cell and set the custom time format to **[h]:mm**. If this solves the problem, then post as a solution - it will help someone in the future.

Comment: One column for one day?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SU.

It is worth knowing how Excel stores and deals with time and date formatted data. In the background, it is actually storing a single number (regardless whether it is time or date or time and date) called the date serial number. This serial number is the number of days (including fractions for hours/mins/secs/etc) since 0 January 1900. So, if you enter data in `A1` as `12:00` and then change the format to "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm", Excel will actually display "1900/01/00  12:00:00". If in B1 you enter the formula `=A1+1`, you are adding exactly one day and Excel will show "1900/01/01  12:00:00". If you change the formatting to "numbers", you will get `0.5` and `1.5`.

To get the answer you are after, make sure the time you input is "0 biased"  i.e. relative to 1900/01/00 00:00 otherwise adding time together will not make any sense. When adding "0 biased" times together, Excel will naturally let every 24hours spill into a new day. If you are only display hh:mm, you will not see the roll-over into days. You have a few options to view the data correctly:

1. Set a custom time format to [h]:mm or [m]:ss to display in either total hours or total minutes
2. Set the answer's format to "numbers" and multiply by 24 to get the total hours. So a date serial of e.g. 1.7 days will be 40.8 hours, or 40 hours and 48 minutes (.8 * 60).